# ReactJs/Redux Maintaining state between reducer calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Ok, this is a noob question, no doubt, but I couldn't find a good answer in my searches. I've built a simple ReactJs/Redux app and it appears to work fine, except that when I change one value on the page, it blanks out the other in my display of state. What I can't tell is whether the problem is in my display of state or if I'm accidentally mutating state. Advice on best practices and/or debugging in this environment is welcome.

I have a textbox and a drop-down and I display the state (I think). When I change either the dropdown or the text box, the other value goes blank (in my display).

Here's my container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
    changeLogFilterMessageContains,
    changeTestDropdownSelectedValue
} from '../actions';
import { LogsPage } from '../components/LogsPage';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    logFilters: state.logFilters,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    changeLogFilterMessageContains,
    changeTestDropdownSelectedValue,
};

const LogsPageContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(LogsPage);

export default LogsPageContainer;
```

and my LogsPage:

```
import React, {
    Component,
} from 'react';

export class LogsPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Logs Page</h1>
                <p>Message contains:
                    <input type="text" value={this.props.logFilters.logFilterMessageContains}
                        onChange={e => this.props.changeLogFilterMessageContains({ logFilterMessageContains: e.target.value })} />
                    <br />
                    <select onChange={e => this.props.changeTestDropdownSelectedValue({ testDropdownSelectedValue: e.target.value })}>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="One">One</option>
                        <option value="Two">Two</option>
                        <option value="Three">Three</option>
                        <option value="Four">Four</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>logFilterMessageContains: {this.props.logFilters.logFilterMessageContains}</li>
                    <li>testDropdownSelectedValue: {this.props.logFilters.testDropdownSelectedValue}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LogsPage;
```

and my reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export const geod = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ACTIVATE_GEOD':
            return action.geod;
        case 'CLOSE_GEOD':
            return {};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const logFilters = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_LOG_FILTER_MESSAGE_CONTAINS':
            return action.logFilterMessageContains;
        case 'CHANGE_TEST_DROPDOWN':
            return action.testDropdownSelectedValue;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    geod,
    logFilters
});
```

And, my actions:

```
export const activateGeod = geod => ({
    type: 'ACTIVATE_GEOD',
    geod,
});

export const closeGeod = () => ({
    type: 'CLOSE_GEOD',
});

export const changeLogFilterMessageContains = logFilterMessageContains => ({
    type: 'CHANGE_LOG_FILTER_MESSAGE_CONTAINS',
    logFilterMessageContains,
});

export const changeTestDropdownSelectedValue = testDropdownSelectedValue => ({
    type: 'CHANGE_TEST_DROPDOWN',
    testDropdownSelectedValue,
});
```

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, so if someone with the know-how wouldn't mind setting me straight, I would appreciate the help.

V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently learned how to use redux and I have found that this is best place to check yourself: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux . The guy speaking is the grandaddy of redux and he explains the bare bones of it all.

The second thing that I have learned is, make sure you have a test for everything; action creators, reducers, and the store.

Look at your `combineReducers`, your store's state is going to look something like this

```
{
    geod: *somevalue*,
    logFilters: *somevalue*
}
```

The value of `logFilters` is determined by your `logFilters` reducer.

Your `logFilters` reducer returns the action 'payload'. You have called these specific names, logFilterMessageContains & testDropdownSelectedValue, but the returned value will become the value of `logFilters` in the store's state. You can access this value in your connected component using `{this.props.logfilters}` (because the structure of your `mapStateToProps`).

Looking at the code I don't think that `this.props.logFilters.logFilterMessageContains` exists in your component. The `logFilterMessageContains` variable only exists is the scope of your reducer and action creators. The value of this variable sets the value of `logFilters` in your store's state only after `changeLogFilterMessageContains` is dispatched.

consider breaking your `logFilters` reducer into two separate reducers. It looks like you are trying to control two independent variables with it.

any questions?

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I will take it. One question: so, I need a reducer for every independent variable in state?

Comment: I would say yes. The combine reducer function amalgamates them into one single reducer, which you could write yourself, but I find it easier to let that function alleviate some of the complication..